Booting issues on the Raspberry Pi 4B
My Raspberry Pi 4B running Pi OS Lite 64-bit is having issues booting. I've watched videos on how to fix it, but none have worked since all only work on the desktop version.
I have installed the OS via the Raspberry Pi Imager (From the Raspberry Pi). It says to hold the SHIFT key to start network installation, but it makes me download another SD card image instead.
Could you please tell me how to fix this?


How are you creating the boot image on the SD card? at this stage of the boot process, it doesn't matter if you are trying to boot lite or desktop version, your SD card is not being recognised as a valid OS. Have you tried a USB thumb drive? Have you tried  firmware recovery image?

Has this pi ever booted? What happens if you press <ESC> and go to diagnostics screen as it states at the bottom of your rather fuzzy image

I have been to the diagnostics screen, but it just says stuff I can't use.

What exactly do you mean by "issues"? Do you mean like you prepared a supposedly-bootable card for the Pi but it got stuck at this screen when you try to get it booted? Is the card inserted to the slot of the Pi or are you using a USB card reader? Is there any (other) USB drive/device connected to the Pi?

I was booting from an SD card and downloaded the image from Raspberry Pi Imager.  The only USB devices that are connected are my keyboard and mouse.

It look like the SD is not recognised by your RPI , you can try to clean the port and sd card and maybe change the sd card.
On the boot screen press esc to display more info you should see the boot order and detail about it. To modify the boot order is a bit strange on the rpi you need to boot first in anyway you can, then run
sudo -E rpi-eeprom-config --edit.
text me once you have more info
